# Install DL4J on Windows

Tags: java, git, maven, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I have just followed the steps given on: https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/getting-started/quickstart (cloning it from github, executing mvn clean install, import the project into IntelliJ) and I was able to run the examples in IntelliJ.

However, I am a bit unsure if these steps are enough for me to be able to use DL4J libraries outside of the examples (And How I would be able to do it?).

If I would want to use DL4J libraries in my own project, would it be enough just to create a new maven project and add the dependency for DL4J in the POM.XML file? If that is the case, could you please give me an example?

Or the guide I followed above is just for the examples and not for the actual libraries?

If that is the case, if anyone has the time, could you give me a detailed explanation on how I can install the DL4J libraries and everything that is required to run it smoothly (and how I would be able to use the library in the future with an example?)?

I am running Windows 10, JDK 1.8.0.65 64 bit, Maven 3.3.9, IntelliJ.

I'm sorry if my question seems stupid and basic, but I got to struggle with the installation.

Thank you for your time to read my issue!

Comment: There's nothing to really "install". It's just a library. The examples are meant to be a reference project. That project is also the current snapshot of dependencies needed. All you should need for most things is deeplearning4j-core and an nd4j backend (nd4j-native-platform) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
So, if I clone the two repos (nd4j and deeplearning4j) from github and run "mvn clean install" in git bash, the only thing I will have left is to include the dependencies in the POM.XML file (to nd4j and deeplearning4j) in my own maven project and am good to go?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why not use maven central though? I don't see why you need to build from source. Dl4j isn't just something you clone and install. It has build steps and c code involved. I'm going to ask that you refrain building from source unless you have a good reason. Please read our quick start: http://deeplearning4j.org/quickstart

If you want to build from source (no you shouldn't): read this: http://deeplearning4j.org/buildinglocally

If you read our docs was there somewhere that indicated you should do this? If so we should get rid of it. *None* of our docs tell you to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do to start actually using it to clone the examples:

```
git clone https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples.git
```

It is described here: https://deeplearning4j.org/quickstart#

.. and from that point you can start by modifying the examples locally on your machine. You copy paste, put your code, do whatever you like with the examples.